# Press a first button, hold it, and move your finger to another button, and activate this one, on Android?

Tags: java, android, button

I try to create an application on Android, but I have some difficulties to find the exact words to express my problem. So, I have 3 buttons, And, I want when the user press a button, and hold it, and move his finger hover an other one, the other one runs its code. Actually, I'm using the onTouchListener() method and the ACTION_DOWN and ACTION_UP to know for each button when it is pressed and released to run a certain code for each button. But it's not what i want exactly...

Well, I know it's not totaly clear, but if you have some questions, I can try to answer. I find another post that describes my problem i guess, but it's not clear to me...

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't understand your problem, there is no way we will. With that in mind perhaps you should look at the other actions available to you such as ACTION_HOVER_ENTER.

Comment: Thanks for your help ! I understand my problem, but I only have difficulties to explain it i think, but i guess you understand what I mean, I have read the documentation from Android about different MotionEvent to try to find the one correspondong to my  problem, and i tried a lot from the list, but i didn t find one working from the ones tested. :x

Answer (score 0):

button.setOnGenericMotionListener(); // listen for generic motions

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help, i'll will test this as soon as possible :)